# I have a function when i click checked it is calling function again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, pie-chart

demo() function is a pie chart i have a toggle button with check box toggle button whenever i toggle it demo() function is calling which is fine but it is creating copy of the pie chart whenever i am clicking on check box(toggle button) it changes the value around the chart which is working fine but it is calling the pie chart function again and again and multiple pie chart are creating with toggle button. what should i do get the new chart only once i mean it will not create a copy of pie chart and remove the old one?

```
async function renderTradesInfo() {
    let tradeOrders = await TradesInformation();

    totalTrades = tradeOrders.data.total_orders;
    

    let ThirtydOrders = tradeOrders.data.orders_placed_30d;
    let ThirtydOrder = `${ThirtydOrders}`;
    let thirtydOrderTrade=  $("#tradeCharts").find("#thirtydOrderTrade");
    thirtydOrderTrade.html(ThirtydOrder);

    let checkedValue = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
    if(!checkedValue){
        closedOrdersTrade(tradeOrders);
        totalTrades = tradeOrders.data.total_orders;
        demo(totalTrades);
    }

    $('#checkbox1').on('change', function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            let openProfitOrders = tradeOrders.data.open_profit_orders;
            let openProfitOrder = `${openProfitOrders} Profit`;
            let tradeChartProfit=  $("#tradeCharts").find(".tradeChartProfit");
            tradeChartProfit.html(openProfitOrder);
        
            let openLossOrders = tradeOrders.data.open_loss_orders;
            let openLossOrder = `${openLossOrders} Loss`;
            let tradeChartLoss=  $("#tradeCharts").find(".tradeChartLoss");
            tradeChartLoss.html(openLossOrder);
            
            // totalTrades = tradeOrders.data.open_orders;
            demo(totalTrades);
        }
        else {
            closedOrdersTrade(tradeOrders);
            // totalTrades = tradeOrders.data.closed_orders;
            demo(totalTrades);
        }
     
     });
}
```

This is the piechart function which i want to update on toggle but it is creating new piechart

```
function demo(totalTrades){

const chartData = [
    { name: 'Loss', value: 10},
    { name: 'Profit', value: 90}
  ]

  const colors = ['#EB5757', '#1EE8B7']
  
  const margin = { top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 45 },
    width = 190 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 210,
    radius = width / 2
  
  const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(colors)
  
  const arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 25)
  
  const textArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 50)
    .innerRadius(radius - 50)
  
  const pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(d => d.value)
  
  const svg = d3.select('.wrapper')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2 - 30})`)
  
  const g = svg.selectAll('.arc')
    .data(pie(chartData))
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
  
  g.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .style('fill', d => colorScale(d.data.name))
    .style('stroke', 'none')
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween('d', chartTween)
  
  // g.append('text')
  //   .transition()
  //   .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  //   .duration(1000)
  //   .attr('transform', d => `translate(${textArc.centroid(d)})`)
  //   .attr('dx', '-3em')
  //   .attr('dy', '.75em')
  //   .text(d => d.data.value)
  //   .attr('font-size', '20px')
  //   .attr('fill', '#fff')
  
  g.append('text')
    .html('Total Trades')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('class', 'center-text')
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(0, -10)')
    .attr('fill', '#fff')

  g.append('text')
    .html(totalTrades)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('class', 'center-text')
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(0, 10)')
    .attr('fill', '#FFFFFF')
  
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legendLinear')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(70, 330)')
  
  const colorLegend = d3.legendColor()
    .orient('horizontal')
    .shapeWidth(60)
    .scale(colorScale)
  
  svg.select('.legendLinear')
    .call(colorLegend)
  
  // helper functions
  function chartTween(b) {
    b.innerRadius = 0
    const i = d3.interpolate({ startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0 }, b)
    return function (t) { return arc(i(t)) }
  }
}
```

Comment: So do you call renderTradesInfo more than once? If yes, you are binding the onchange event multiple times.

Comment: @epascarello i am calling this function on window reload